# Ошибка при инициализации переменной типа XmlTypeMapping

Tags: c#, .net

Есть следующая иерархия классов:

```
public class XmlTypeMapping_init
{
    public XmlTypeMapping tm;
    public XmlTypeMapping_init()
    {
        tm = (new SoapReflectionImporter().ImportTypeMapping(typeof(SOAP_Serializer)));
    }
}

public class SOAP_Serializer:XmlTypeMapping_init
{
    private StreamWriter file;
    private XmlSerializer xml_s;        
    public SOAP_Serializer()
        : base()
    {
        xml_s = new XmlSerializer(tm);
    }
 ...
}
```

При вызове указанного конструктора класса `SOAP_Serializer` (`SOAP_Serializer s = new SOAP_Serializer();`) происходит вызов родительского конструктора, и на строке

```
tm = (new SoapReflectionImporter().ImportTypeMapping(typeof(SOAP_Serializer)));
```

появляется ошибка:

> Невозможно сериализовать System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping, т. к. он не имеет беспараметрического конструктора

Comment: `XmlSerializer` требует, чтобы у сериализуемого типа был конструктор по умолчанию. Тип `XmlTypeMapping`  такого не имеет. Можете попробовать использовать другой сериализатор (`DataContractSerializer`, `JsonSerializer` и т.д.), но лучше расскажите, чего хотите сделать.

Comment: Это понятно, но происходит ли в строке, на которой появляется ошибка, сериализация? Хочу создать свой класс, использующий SOAP-сериализацию. Пример использования XmlSerializer для сериализации в SOAP здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/d5wt2he6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SoapReflectionImporter` кушает все публичные поля. `SOAP_Serializer` наследуется от `XmlTypeMapping_init`, у которого есть публичное поле `XmlTypeMapping tm`, которое пытается сериализоваться. Сделайте его `protected` (коль скоро хотите использовать в наследнике), или поставьте атрибут `[SoapIgnore]`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Только я не понял, почему ужесточение с точки зрения модификатора доступа дало такой эффект? SoapReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping генерирует сопоставление элемента схемы XML для указанного типа платформы .NET Framework. А где же здесь сериализация?

Comment: @AN90 видимо, в момент создания маппинга публичные члены типа проверяются на возможность сериализации, и в случае если проверка не срабатывает, выбрасывается исключение. Если очень интересно, можете покопаться в коде и найти это место: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/SoapReflectionImporter.cs,716cc6058ebcbf57